# UnicodeDecodeError with compilemessages django translator

Tags: django

I get this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while I want to comiple `.po` file using

```
python django.admin.py manage.py compilemessages
```

This is my django.po file:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2014-05-28 11:39+0000\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: blog/forms.py:6
msgid "name"
msgstr ""

#: blog/forms.py:7
msgid "e-mail"
msgstr ""

#: blog/forms.py:8
msgid "comment"
msgstr ""

#: blog/Template/post.html:34
msgid "send"
msgstr ""
```

Traceback:

```
 python2.7 manage.py compilemessages
processing file django.po in /home/arash/Lab/django/arash_blog/conf/locale/fa_IR/LC_MESSAGES
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py", line 71, in handle
    compile_messages(self.stdout, locale=locale)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py", line 42, in compile_messages
    if not f.endswith('.po'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?    This can't be all of the meesage: what is the rest of the traceback?

Comment: i use python version 2.7 and https://dpaste.de/c2z9

Answer (score 1):

Look at your traceback, obviously, your `.po` file is not at fault:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py", line 42, in compile_messages
    if not f.endswith('.po'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

See that `if not`?

There's (at least) one file, most likely a Python file, in your repo that has a non-ASCII character in it. All you have to do is find it and add this at the top:

```
#coding:utf-8
```

Or whatever encoding is used for that file. Since you're on Linux, it's most likely indeed going to be `utf-8`, but that could depend on your editor.

---

If you have trouble finding said file, just open `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/compilemessages.py`, and before that line 42 `if` clause, add a `print f` line.

Then run the command. You should see the culprit just above the traceback.

Once you've found it, just remove that print statement.